# iron-list and spinner do not work together

Tags: polymer

I have an `iron-list` displaying my items:

```
<iron-list id="list" items="[[items]]" as="item"  selection-enabled multi-selection>
  <template>
  ...
  </template>
</iron-list>
```

Everything works fine, but I get `items` from an external service, and it takes time, so I'd like to display a spinner until the data is received.

So I tried this:

```
<template is="dom-if" if="[[!items]]">
  <paper-spinner-lite alt="Loading items list" active></paper-spinner-lite>
</template>

<template is="dom-if" if="[[items]]">
  <iron-list id="list" items="[[items]]" as="item"  selection-enabled multi-selection>
    <template>
       ...
    </template>
  </iron-list>
</template>
```

but it does not work -- `items` are not displayed at all even though it is loaded from the backend service.

By experimenting, I found that `items` stopped displaying after I added the first `<template is="dom-if" if="[[!items]]">`. After I removed it (keeping the spinner and second `template if`), `items` started to be displayed when it loaded.

Where is the mistake?

Comment: Shouldn't the second template have `if="[[items]]"`? (no exclamation mark)

Comment: Yep. There's also a typo in the closing tag for the first template. Even with those issues fixed, `if=[[!items]]` would always be `false`.

Comment: Yes, sorry - just mistake then copy-pasted code. Of course in source code second template contained if=[[items]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`items` is an `Array`, and arrays (even empty ones) in Javascript are [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), so your binding of `[[!items]]` would always evaluate to `false`.

You could use a [computed binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#annotated-computed) to evaluate the length of `items`:

```
// template
<template is="dom-if" if="[[_isEmpty(items.*)]]">...</template>
<template is="dom-if" if="[[!_isEmpty(items.*)]]">...</template>

// script
Polymer({
  ...
  _isEmpty: function() {
    return this.items.length === 0;
  }
);
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.5.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="iron-list/iron-list.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-spinner/paper-spinner-lite.html">
</head>

<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <style>
      iron-list {
        height: 400px;
      }
    </style>
    <template>
      <template is="dom-if" if="[[_isEmpty(items.*)]]">
        <paper-spinner-lite alt="Loading items list" active></paper-spinner-lite>
      </template>

      <template is="dom-if" if="[[!_isEmpty(items.*)]]">
        <iron-list items="[[items]]">
          <template>
            <div>[[index]]: [[item]]</div>
          </template>
        </iron-list>
      </template>
    </template>
    <script>
      HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
        Polymer({
          is: 'x-foo',
          properties: {
            items: {
              type: Array,
              value: function() {
                return [];
              }
            }
          },
          _isEmpty: function() {
            return this.items.length === 0;
          },
          _loadData: function() {
            console.log('loading data...');
            for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
              this.push('items', Math.random());
            }
          },
          ready: function() {
            this.async(this._loadData, 2000);
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

<sup>[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/bewrGd?editors=1001)</sup>

Or you could declare a `Boolean` property, set to `true` by an observer based on `items` (which is basically a longer version of the solution above):

```
// template
<template is="dom-if" if="[[_isEmpty]]">...</template>
<template is="dom-if" if="[[!_isEmpty]]">...</template>

// script
Polymer({
  ...
  properties: {
    ...
    _isEmpty: {
      type: Boolean,
      value: true
    }
  },
  observers: [
    '_setEmpty(items.*)'
  ],
  _setEmpty: function() {
    this._isEmpty = this.items.length === 0;
  }
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.5.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="iron-list/iron-list.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-spinner/paper-spinner-lite.html">
</head>

<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <style>
      iron-list {
        height: 400px;
      }
    </style>
    <template>
      <template is="dom-if" if="[[_isEmpty]]">
        <paper-spinner-lite alt="Loading items list" active></paper-spinner-lite>
      </template>

      <template is="dom-if" if="[[!_isEmpty]]">
        <iron-list items="[[items]]">
          <template>
            <div>[[index]]: [[item]]</div>
          </template>
        </iron-list>
      </template>
    </template>
    <script>
      HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
        Polymer({
          is: 'x-foo',
          properties: {
            items: {
              type: Array,
              value: function() {
                return [];
              }
            },
            _isEmpty: {
              type: Boolean,
              value: true
            }
          },
          observers: [
            '_setEmpty(items.*)'
          ],
          _setEmpty: function() {
            this._isEmpty = this.items.length === 0;
          },
          _loadData: function() {
            console.log('loading data...');
            for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
              this.push('items', Math.random());
            }
          },
          ready: function() {
            this.async(this._loadData, 2000);
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

<sup>[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/MejvYp?editors=1001)</sup>